# GStreamer bus sends None message

Tags: python, gstreamer

I've been using pygst on a project and it's been working fine. I'm trying to migrate it to the new introspection system (GI), but I've been getting a different behavior.

In the old pygst I have something like this:

```
... # other imports
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
... # other imports

gobjects.threads_init()

...

def my_handler(bus, message):
    # handle the message

...

player = gst.element_factory_make('playbin2', 'my_player')
bus = player.get_bus()
bus.connect('message', my_handler)
bus.add_signal_watch()
...
player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
# start the main Glib loop
```

The *message* parameter has an attribute *.type* which can be used for selective processing (I'm only interested in the end of stream (EOS) and error). Using the new system I have:

```
... # other imports
from gi.repository import Gst
import glib
import gobject
.... # other imports

gobject.threads_init()

loop = glib.MainLoop(None, False)

def bus_handler(bus, message):
    print message
    # handle the message
...

Gst.init_check(None)
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin2', 'my_player')
player.set_property('uri', 'file:///home/kenji/button.ogg')
bus = player.get_bus()
bus.connect('message', bus_handler)
bus.add_signal_watch()
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
# start the main loop
```

However, the handler always receives the parameter *message* as *None*. I've tried filtering these out, but I still get nothing (i.e. all messages are *None*).

I've read a lot of the GStreamer documentation (especially on GstBus, add_signal_watch() and playbin2) but I didn't find anything related to this behavior. I've checked the Gst *gir* file and I've seen that add_watch() cannot be introspected, so that's a dead end. The glib main loop in this above example is just to make things shorter without a full GTK example, but the real thing uses Gtk.main() (giving exactly the same behavior).

I'm using GStreamer 0.10.35.0 (as informed by Gst.version()) on Arch Linux 64, but I've tested the same behavior on GStreamer 0.10.32.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit.

Is there any alternative to bus.connect()? Am I using it in the wrong way? I've spent quite a few hours hunting down this bug, I would really appreciate any insight on this. Thanks! =)

Comment: I found this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631901

Basically, it's not implemented yet.

Comment: I can confirm that this is fixed in gstreamer 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `add_signal_watch_full()`, which is unfortunately more verbose. It works fine though, and I can receive messages on my handler.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Could you maybe provide some sample code?

Comment: add_signal_watch_full(1) works for me. I don't know why "1" argument needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the accepted answer is incorrect. The only difference between `add_signal_watch_full` and `add_signal_watch` is that the former lets you set the priority of the event source, while the latter just calls the former with `G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`. You can verify this in the C [source code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/gst/gstbus.c?h=0.10), line number 940. The priority level just affects the order of events fired, should not affect whether the are fired and certainly not the contents of the signal message, which is the issue here. I've even tested it with various values for priority, I'll eat my hat if there is a way that this works. :-)

The real answer is that it doesn't work. PyGObject and GStreamer 0.10 don't work well together. See:

- [GStreamer mailing list thread](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GStreamer-via-PyGObject-introspection-td3797220.html)
- [PyGObject bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631901), as linked above.
- [A useful page from the Novacut Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0#Python_Porting_Guide)

The latter says: "Note that although you can *sort-of* use GStreamer0.10 with PyGI, key functionality is fundamentally broken and wont ever be fixed in GStreamer0.10 (because it would require API breakage)."

Your options, then, are:

- Require GStreamer 1.0.
- Use the old PyGST bindings.
- Use PyGObject with GStreamer 0.10, but without the ability to check for messages like EOS. Only very basic stuff work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan on using GTK with the program, you will have to run a  `gobject.Mainloop()` in order to get messages from the bus. This, like any other mainloop, will freeze the whole program (if it is not threaded), so I usually put something something like:

```
g_loop = threading.Thread(target=gobject.MainLoop().run)
g_loop.daemon = True
g_loop.start()
```

at the end of a program that doesn't need a GUI, but does need Gstreamer.

Comment: This does not answer the question. From the last line of the sample code, the comment indicates that Kenji is aware that a mainloop is required. And your solution does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem but in C.

After long days of debugging, I found that this was happening because my executable was linking to both 0.10 and 1.0, indirectly by other shared libraries I use.

Removing the shared libraries that linked to 0.10 solved my problem.